# Assigning a predetermined level for NA values within a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot below, I want to change `NA`to display "Pending" on the x-axis. How do I achieve this?

Data for the plot comes from a large table and contains `NA` values in the `mth_yr` column. I want to change the labeling only when constructing the plot, this way I know that the transformation happens only within the plot (so I don't forget 6 mths from now).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
            mth_yr = c("Jul2018", "Aug2018", "Sep2018", "Oct2018", "Nov2018",
                       "Dec2018", NA),
            output = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35)
      )

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(mth_yr, levels = c("Jul2018", "Aug2018", "Sep2018", 
                                            "Oct2018", "Nov2018","Dec2018")),
                  y = output)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("")
```

Please help!

Comment: `forcats::fct_explicit_na` does this specifically for factor levels

Comment: camille I tried it, in my code, I `group_by` on `mth_yr` and when I use `forcats::fct_explicit_na(mth_yr)` it changes the name of the column. How to overcome this?

Comment: Without seeing it in your code, I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can use `forcats::fct_explicit_na` to replace the `NA` level with something more specific.

`forcats::as_factor` turns the variable into a factor with levels *in the same order in which they appear*, meaning you don't have to worry about spelling out the levels to override any alphabetical ordering. Then create the "Pending" label.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 mth_yr = c("Jul2018", "Aug2018", "Sep2018", "Oct2018", "Nov2018",
                            "Dec2018", NA),
                 output = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35)
)

with_pending <- df %>%
   mutate(mth_yr = as_factor(mth_yr) %>%
             fct_explicit_na(na_level = "Pending"))
with_pending
#>    mth_yr output
#> 1 Jul2018      5
#> 2 Aug2018     10
#> 3 Sep2018     15
#> 4 Oct2018     20
#> 5 Nov2018     25
#> 6 Dec2018     30
#> 7 Pending     35

ggplot(with_pending, aes(x = mth_yr, y = output)) +
   geom_col() +
   xlab("")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can replace `NA` with `Pending` using `replace_na` before plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  replace_na(list(mth_yr = "Pending")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(mth_yr, levels = c("Jul2018", "Aug2018", "Sep2018", 
                                           "Oct2018", "Nov2018","Dec2018", "Pending")),
             y = output)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("")
```

[image]